# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a slide show, I have written following code but it’s not working most probably due to the reason that this line `$('#contain').children();` is returning `[object Object]` instead of a DOM elements over which I can iterate?

`Complete code:`

```
function startSlideShow(interval) {
//var slides = $('#contain').children();
var slides = $('#contain').children().get();
console.log("0: " + slides);
slides.each(function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            var slide = $(slides[i]).children();
            console.log("1: " + slide);
            $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide[0].src).fadeIn(interval * 100);
            $('#slideDesc').html(slide[1].innerHTML).fadeIn(interval * 100);
        }, interval * 1000);
}
}
```

`in the html:`

```
<article id="imageShow">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="" id="currentImage" />
    </div>
    <div id="imageCover"></div>
</article>

<article id="contain">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/925p6M5.jpg" />
        <span>1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dbBu5rk.jpg" />
        <span>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VFxPGEi.gif" />
        <span>3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
</article>
```

and in console i get errors like: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined'

Comment: At the beginning (this line: var slides = $('#contain).children().get();) you forgot to close the '

Comment: that was typo here, corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for might be

```
function startSlideShow(interval) {
    var slides = $('#contain').children();
    slides.each(function (i, v) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var slide = $(v);
            $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide.children('img').attr('src')).fadeIn(interval * 100);
            $('#slideDesc').html(slide.children('span').html()).fadeIn(interval * 100);
        }, i * interval);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zkFY2/)

Comment: thank you this works but now `setTimeout` function is not working as expected and all images/span are replaced at once not with any delay?

Comment: @Maven what is the interval value passed? it is in milliseconds ie `1000` is 1 second delay... look at the demo fiddle

Comment: `interval` value passed is `10` which `* 1000` should make it 10 secs? but its not.

Comment: @Maven in that case you need to replace `i * interval` with `i * interval * 1000`

Comment: ok done. just one thing isn't it going to increase that delay with every iteration? when i is one it will be `10000` when i is 2 it will be `20000`, i want to keep the delay constant?

Comment: @Maven no it is not... the first item will be shown immediately because `0 * 10 * 1000 == 0`, second item will be shown in 10 seconds and third in 20 seconds from now... ie a 10 sec gap between each item

Answer (score 1):

missing `'`..which i think is a typo... anwyways problem is here,

```
  $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide[0].src).fadeIn(interval * 100);
```

**you don't have an element with id as `currentImage` and hence you are getting an error saying src property is undefined.**

**updated**

try this

```
function startSlideShow(interval) {
var slides = $('#contain').children();
slides.each(function (index, value) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var slide = $(value);
        $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide.find('img').attr('src')).fadeIn(interval * 100);
        $('#slideDesc').html(slide.find('span').html()).fadeIn(interval * 100);
    }, interval * 1000);
});
}
```

Comment: actually i have element with the ID `currentImage`, check my updated question. sorry for missing it before.

Comment: works now, but now `setTimeout` function is not working and all images/span are replaces at once not with a delay?

Comment: opppsss.. sorry i missed `)` near `$('#currentImage').attr('src', slide.find('img').attr('src')` ..updated...try it now.. it should work

Comment: fixed it, but `setTimeout` is still not delaying the execution for the next iteration?

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
var slides = $('#contain).children().get();
```

**With**

```
var slides = $('#contain').children().get();
```

Here you forgot `'` in `id` selector.

If you want to select child element you need to specify which child element you want to get.

```
var slides = $('#contain').children('div').get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying specify the child element, instead of simple mentioning children().